# Dynamic UI for MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC(3). I am trying to look for an idea on how I can render UIs with dynamic controls and is it possible to have it bind with a model/class that is dynamic as well?

Example:
UI has First Name, Address and State (Code only) field from the Member table.
Model/Class contains First Name, Address and State field.

User wants to view State Name but comes from a different table (States table) so I need to add State Name (where State Code=State Code in the Member table) to the UI as well as the model/class.

Additional fields will be based on the tables who has foreign key relationships with the main table.

Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your model contains that field then it will be bound. I'm not 100% following how you mean dynamic though. Think of it this way - the model binder will take posted fields from your form and match their names to a property in the model.

If a property doesn't exist in the model, it won't be found and hence not bound. You 'could' write a method that parses additional fields from your FormsCollection (ie Request.Form["parameter name"]) and puts it into some dynamic collection in your model, however this could get very messy.

Generally with MVC you want to just add your new field to a ViewModel which is essentially a model that you are making specific to that view. You can use a tool like AutoMapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/   to map (copy) property values between your ViewModel and your real model.